# SVG to backgroundImage and overlayImage

Tags: fabricjs

I'm loading an SVG from an URL inside of my fabric canvas. I filter my SVG objects to separate them into 2 groups : the first one is used as background image, the other one as overlay image.

Here is the code :

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(
  site_url,
  (objects,options) => {
    const background = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects.filter(i => i.id.includes('background')), options)
    const overlay = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects.filter(i => i.id.includes('overlay')), options)
    background.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth())
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(background, () => canvas.renderAll())
    overlay.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth())
    canvas.setOverlayImage(overlay, () => canvas.renderAll())

  }, null, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' },
)
```

Here is the expected result :

[image]

This doesn't work. Well, actually, this will work only if all the objects in `background` and in `overlay` share the same size. But since they don't, this actually results in that :

[image: Background (purple) and shadow]

Now, if I change my code to that :

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(
  site_url,
  (objects,options) => {
    const background = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)
    background.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth())
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(background, () => canvas.renderAll())

  }, null, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' },
)
```

Everything works fine, it will result in y first image. I'm pretty sure it comes from scaleToWidth being used twice, and therefore resulting in a backgroundImage and overlayImage of different sizes, but I have no idea about how to maintain my SVG while scaling both overlayImage and backgroundImage, and I don't think I've seen anything in documentation about loadSVGfromURL handling it.

Comment: can you create fiddle/snippet?

Comment: @Durga sure : https://jsfiddle.net/Sashkan/j48z1oas/

Comment: Dimensions of background and front objects is different, I guess. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j48z1oas/7/)

Comment: Yes, but since the SVG is already formatted to make sure that all layers are in their right place, I thought I could scale the whole thing instead of having to scale both overlay and background.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if anyone struggle, you have to make sure that objects used for background and overlay share the same size. If not, you'll have to set their scale yourself :

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(
  svg_url,
  (objects, options) => {
    const loadedBackObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects.filter(o => o.id.split(' ').includes('back')), options)

    const ratio1 = this.props.size / options.width
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(
      loadedBackObjects,
      () => {
        canvas.selection = true
        const loadedFrontObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects.filter(o => o.id.split(' ').includes('front')), options)
        const ratio2 = this.props.size / loadedFrontObjects.width
        canvas.setOverlayImage(loadedFrontObjects, () => {
          if (canvas.overlayImage._objects) {
            canvas.overlayImage._objects.filter(i => i.id.split(' ').includes('Heather')).map((i) => {
              i.set({ opacity: this.props.variation.heather ? 1 : 0 })
            })
          }
        }, {
          scaleX: ratio2,
          scaleY: ratio2,
          top: loadedFrontObjects.top * ratio1,
          left: loadedFrontObjects.left * ratio1,
        })
        canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
      }, {
        scaleX: ratio1,
        scaleY: ratio1,
        top: loadedBackObjects.top * ratio1,
        left: loadedBackObjects.left * ratio1,
      },
    )
    canvas.renderAll()
  }, null, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' },
)
```